# Infopath and Active Directory

Tags: infopath

I have an evaluation form that I am building in infopath. How this form is going to be used is. The manager will fill out the form and then an entire workflow behind it.

What i want to do is in the first field I want to type in a users name and it then populates the rest of the fields based on that users Active Directory. Is there a way to do this without adding a button?

Or does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by setting up a data connection to the User Profile Service and querying that data connection. It can be done entirely without code, but with a lot of clicks and you need to keep your wits together.

Clayton Cobb has a very detailed and very good walkthrough here: http://claytoncobb.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/userprofileservice-extended/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to type the user's name, I recommend using the People Picker control. Then you can query user accounts and it will store the proper account and display names, and email address that you can then use with the UserProfileService.asmx to lookup user profile details on that user.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2010/04/08/improvements-to-the-person-group-picker-in-infopath-2010.aspx